# ¿Como obtener el dato con el id mas alto

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una pagina para que puedas editar el texto de notificacion de la pagina principal (Ya logre subir el texto a la base de datos) pero no tengo ni la menor idea de como obtenerlo, entonces pense quiza puedo buscar el dato con el id mas alto por ejemplo:

ID | Texto|

1  | Hola bienvenido| 
2  | Bienvenido a mi pagina web|
3  | Hola "Nombre de usuario" | <--- Entonces quiero obtener el texto del id 
mas alto que en este caso es el 3 para en mi pagina principal mostrarlo

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer esto.

Realmente no tengo nada de codigo mas que la conexion con la base de datos

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "despacho_edit_website_admin";

$table_user = "users";
$table_txt = "txt_parrafo";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
```

?>

despues del codigo PHP va mi codigo HTML, y la parte de notificacion donde quiero cambiar el texto es la siguiente.

```
<div class="txtnotification">

            <p>Te ayudamos a presentar tu declaración anual para personas físicas. </br> Regímenes: Asalariado,
                Arrendamiento, Honorarios, Actividades profesionales y empresariales.</p>

        </div>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.

PD. Mi base de datos se llama: txt_parrafo

:)

Comment: ¿Cuales son los campos de la tabla donde estan guardados los usuarios?

Comment: Para poder mostrar el usuario actual tienes que crear un login que cree una sesion de lo contrario no se va poder mostrar el nombre de usuario al menos del usuario logeado

Comment: Lo de el username es solo de ejemplo lo que quiero hacer es obtener el valor Texto de la base de datos txt_parrafo.

Answer (score 1):

La consulta SQL que te entrega la fila con mayor "id" es:

```
select *
from t
order by id desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Y como puedo obtener el texto de la fila con el id más alto?

Comment: La consulta anterior entrega todas las columnas de la última fila. Si sólo te interesa una columna en particular, reemplaza el `*` por el nombre de la columna que quieres.

Comment: Ok gracias en un momento lo intento.

Comment: ok, pero como imprimo el valor dentro del columna Texto. Ahora tengo esto:

Comment: <?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "despacho_edit_website_admin";

$table_user = "users";
$table_txt = "txt_parrafo";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

$q = "SELECT Texto from txt_parrafo order by id desc limit 1";
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$q);

echo "$q";

?>

Comment: Pero si imprimo la varialble $q con un echo obtengo lo siguiente: SELECT Texto from txt_parrafo order by id desc limit 1

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar la función MAX()

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE tabla.campo = ( SELECT MAX(tabla.campo) FROM tabla);
```